# Does random walk have more concentration surrounding the origin?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walks

Consider a simple random walk $S_n$ on one dimension, starting at $0$. In this case, $S_n$ fluctuates between $-\infty$ and $\infty$, but intuition says that it might stay more often in an interval surrounding the origin. To formulate this, consider an interval $A=[-d, d]$, and introduce a random variable $1_A(S_n)=1$ if $S_n\in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Consider for some $f\in [0,1]$, the probability

$$Pr[\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{j=0}^n 1_A(S_j)}{n}\geq f]$$

I am not quite sure whether the definition is sensible, as the limit might not exist, but in that case, one could replace by $\lim\sup$ or $\lim\inf$.

The question is, what's the property of this probability?

Note that for finite ergodic Markov chains, similar problems can be answered easily by looking at stationary distributions, but for here, essentially we have a null-recurrent Markov chain.

Comment: This is **not** what you want to consider, because $\dfrac{\sum_{j=0}^n 1_A(S_j)}{n+1}$, which is the fraction of time $\le n$ the process spends in the interval $A$, goes to $0$ a.s. as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Your intuition is wrong.  Just wait until the walk reaches some other interval $B$ of the same length as $A$ and then forget the past.  It can only be that in the limit the walk spends as much time in $B$ as it does in $A$, as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: check the robbins kallianpur law

Comment: @RobertIsrael, it is well possible, but how to prove that?

Comment: I saw an answer but not it is deleted now, could someone explain why it is deleted? thanks.

Comment: The random walk is not positive recurrent.  Using the Strong Law of Large Numbers, the fraction of time spent in any given state goes to $0$ almost surely.  The fraction of time spent in $A$ is the sum of the fractions spent in each member of $A$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael   Many thanks for the comments. I just realize that indeed, as pointed by you, the formulation is wrong, I should have considered $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P[{\sum_{i=0}^n 1_A(S_i) \over n} \leq x]$. This is related to the arcsin law, but I am not really clear about that.

Comment: it is possible for the deleted answer to be re-posted here -- it might be useful for educational purposes. Thanks.

Comment: @maomao: Please edit the question to reflect the formulation you actually want to consider.  Comments are hard to spot.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to the reformulation of the problem in comments. Using Markov's inequality for $x>0$, we obtain 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\left(\frac{\sum_{j=0}^n I_A(S_j)}{n}>x\right) &\le \mathbb E\frac{\sum_{j=0}^n I_A(S_j)}{nx} = 
\frac{1}{nx}\sum_{j=0}^n \mathbb P(S_j\in A )\le \frac{1}{nx}\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{C}{\sqrt {j+1}}\\
&\le C_1\frac{\sqrt n}{nx}\to 0, \quad  n\to \infty. 
\end{align*}
Here, I used an estimate for concentration function $\mathbb P(S_j\in [-d,d])\le C(2d+1)/\sqrt{j}$ for all $j$ and a constant $C$ that does not depend on $j$ and $d$, see Theorem 9 in Chapter 3 of Petrov's book  "Sums of independent random variables".

Clearly, $\sum_{j=0}^n I_A(S_j)$ is of order $\sqrt n$.